# How to convert html contents including divs and ng-grids/tables to pdf using jspdf

Tags: jspdf, fromhtml

I want to convert entire html page to pdf. Thanks to stackoverflow, i got idea, but i want to convert both divs and ng-grids.

Try1: While including both in specialElementHandlers, data and column headers in grid are not displayed properly in pdf. [column headers are displayed as individual rows and unwanted ng-grid code snippets are captured (Total Items: 0
(Showing Items: 0)
Selected Items: 0
Page Size:
/ 1)]

Try2: After converting all my divs to tables, some data are not properly displayed in pdf. Data are not properly placed in table structure.

Kindly let me know, if this is due to html design issue or jspdf property setups.

Comment: Does anyone know, while converting multiple rows (all designed using divs) into pdf, all columns are displayed as "individual row". anybody can throw light on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to an image and insert your image in a html document. Or you put this document in a ftp server and load this.

Comment: thanks for your reply. since content is being captured as image, pdf qaulity is poor.